# Can I read from stdin in a non-canonical way?

Tags: linux, rust

Is there any way one could read from *stdin* in [non-canonical mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Noncanonical-Input.html) under Linux? Non-canonical input means that calls to `read()` on *stdin* shall return as soon as the user types, which is not the default behaviour, as one can see by trying:

```
// Create a buffer
let mut buffer :[u8; 1] = [0];
// Loops over the input from stdin, one character a time
while io::stdin().read(&mut buffer).unwrap() > 0 {
    println!("{:?}", buffer);
}
```

This code waits for the user to press <kbd>return</kbd> to print the contents of `buffer`. The desired behaviour would be for it to print as the user typed. In the documentation for [`Stdin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html) (the struct returned by the `stdin()` call in the code above), there is no reference to how one could change this default behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without external crates or unsafe FFI code. You will probably want to use the [termios](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) functions. Specifically, see `ICANON` and `tcsetattr`. The crate [nix](https://github.com/carllerche/nix-rust) has bindings for these functions. See [here](https://github.com/cpjreynolds/rustty/blob/master/src/core/termctl.rs) for an example of how to use them in Rust.